# Subclass NSDate, no changing behaviour, just add a tag?

Tags: nsdate, subclass

I need to sort I need to subclass NSDate to add a tag, I don't need to change its behaviour, do I still need to implement my own:

- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
- (id)initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;

as stated in apple's documentation? If so, how do I do it?

currently I just created a class extends NSDate with a tag attribute, but how do I initialise it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDate is a class cluster, not a simple class. It is not wise to subclass a class cluster unless you know exactly what you are doing; see [How do I subclass NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657275/how-do-i-subclass-nsdate)

I would recommend that you create your own class containing an NSDate and a tag, and extend as needed:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  NSDate *_date;
  NSUInteger _tag;
}
@end
```

Add the appropriate properties, etc for easy dot-notation access.

Comment: Or use associative references, which have the advantage of keeping the same class.